# How to post multiple object to spring-boot?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to send 2 objects from Angular to Spring, I don't know how should looks my method in Controller. When I send just one object all is working with 2 are problems.

My service

```
savePurchasesInvoice(invoice: GpInvoice, invoiceItems: GpInvoiceitem[]) : Observable<Object>{
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/InvoiceAPI/invoice/new/', {invoice: invoice, invoiceItems: invoiceItems});
  }
```

My method in the controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/new")
public void createInvoice(@RequestBody() GpInvoice gpInvoice) {
    mInvoiceService.saveAndFlush(gpInvoice, null);
}
```

How should looks method in the controller?

Comment: You're not sending two objects. You're sending a single object, with two attributes named invoice and invoiceItems. Your controller method should thus take, as argument, a class which has two properties named invoice and invoiceItems, too. The structure of the Java class should match the structure of the JSON.

Comment: That said, it's quite strange that the invoice items are not part of the invoice objects itself.

Comment: it is working now